# MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException in readEntity() method in Dropwizard

Tags: java, rest, jersey, glassfish, dropwizard

I have read similar questions to this, but none of them was a solution to my problem. So I don't think it's a duplicate

I have to connect to an external service, get response from it and read given values. So first, I made a POJO with response representation

```
public class ServiceResponse {
    @JsonProperty
    public List<MyEntity> entities;
    @JsonProperty
    public Integer status;

    public ServiceResponse(List<MyEntity> entities, Integer status) {
        this.entities = entities;
        this.status = status;
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

In tests I mocked the communication class, so it's not a problem, the response is always present.

Now I have a method, that maps response to my POJO class.

```
ServiceResponse servResponse = response.readEntity(ServiceResponse.class);
```

Simple as that. But, when this line is called, I got an error:

> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException:
>   MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/html, type=class
>   com.mycompany.ServiceResponse, genericType=class
>   com.mycompany.ServiceResponse.    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:231)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:808)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:326)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse$1.call(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:115)
>     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:419)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.runInScopeIfPossible(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:267)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:112)

I didn't quite expected that something may go wrong here. I would rather fought that Jackson would cause troubles, but not Jersey. How to solve this error?

I'm using DW 0.9.2.

Comment: You're probably getting an error html response page. Why don't you check it as a string, and check the status. You might get some insight. If not, post the html and the status. Maybe someone else has an idea

Comment: And as an side, once you _do_ get the right JSON data, you will need a no-arg constructor in your model class or Jackson will fail in deserialization

Comment: Just as I said, there is always a good answer, because i mocked this external service. `when(/*requestMethod*/).thenReturn(Response.ok(new ServiceResponse(entities,0)).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build());`

Comment: I think Paul's comment should be an answer. It saved me.